# Existe uma função para apresentar as variáveis definidas?

Tags: php, variáveis, debug

Existe uma forma de dar um "var_dump" em todas as variáveis instanciadas naquele contexto, sem ter que colocar cada uma dentro do var_dump()?

Comment: Você tem o xDebug instalado?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[get_defined_vars()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-defined-vars.php): pega todas a variáveis definidas no [escopo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)(gobal ou local dependendo do local da chamada da função) e depois você pode executar um `print_r` ou `var_dump` para visualizar seus respectivos valores. Também é retornado o valor das [superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_FILE`, `$_SERVER`, `$_COOKIE`, etc.

Escopo global:

```
<?php
$nome = 'joão';
$idade = 30;
$profissao = 'programador';
$itens = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

$arr = get_defined_vars();
```

Escopo local:

```
<?php
function foo(){
    $local = 'exibe apenas a variavel $local';
    $arr = get_defined_vars();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
}

foo();
```

[**Exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gud9-qwey)

Comment: Perfect, valeu fera!

Answer (score 7):

Além da função `get_defined_vars()`, citada na resposta do @perdeu, em determinadas situações existe outra que pode ser muito útil.

A função [`get_defined_constants()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-defined-constants.php) exibe todas as constantes definidas e seus valores.

Comment: Bacana, vou anotar também!